# Azure Devops: Continue deployment not being fire when pipeline generates a new artifact

Tags: azure-devops, devops, pipeline, release, continuous-deployment

I have a solution where I want to implement the whole CI/CD circuit, Its a simple Web API in dotnet core 3.1
When it finished, my pipeline build triggers the release deployment, but somehow it stays idle until I manually select `"deploy"`, and I want that step to do it on automatic, if the build passes the checks on the pipeline then, it should trigger an automatic release to my environment.

Comment: Can you add some details?
E.g. if you have `yml` version of your build pipeline? If you have "CD" part as multistaged `yml` pipeline or a separate "release"?

Comment: Thanks @JleruOHeP ! but I already found the solution.I posted it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I'm dumb the release trigger needs to be set here:

[image]

and I didnt do it.

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT, thanks for the heads up!, will do.